# Is there a way to have objects in unity occluded by human bodies?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I have an object in unity that I need to be hidden by any person's body. I tried the occlusion setting in MRTK to no avail.

[spatial awareness MRTK setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKwAt.png)

The occlusion only works on well-defined surfaces like tables and walls, but I need the object to be hidden behind a person's body. I've heard that the HoloLens has this capability but may need assistance from Kinect azures. I was wondering if anyone could point me towards the right direction. Any help would be appreciated!

Unity Version I am using: 2020.3.38
MRTK features: 2.8.2

Answer (score 1):

The premise of occlusion is to scan the human body and generate the corresponding object, mesh, collision. However, there is currently no out-of-the-box solution available in HoloLens for body scanning. So, you may need some external libraries to detect/scan the human body. As for Azure Kinect, I am not an expert on this and please find support from corresponding channel.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! Can you explain a little more about what you mean by external libraries? Are they compatible with unity projects? Would I need new hardware?

Comment: The external library means 3rd party libraries that are not officially supported by Microsoft, like OpenCV. We cannot guarantee their effectiveness, and we cannot give professional suggestions due to lack of in-depth research on them.